# I want to trigger a socket event from NodeJS backend (socket io, agenda)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, websocket, real-time

I am building an auction-based application on the MERN stack. I am trying to show live products to all the connected users with the synch same (same timer to all users). For this purpose, I am using socket.io. Now we have some scheduled products as well which will get live on some specific set date and time. I am using the agenda library to change the status from schedule to live for that product but HOW do I tell my socket to add the product to the queue and start showing it on all screens with sync time?
Do I need to use any backend trigger which hits the socket to turn on the emitter in setInterval and show it to all the users? Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to call `io.emit('update event name goes here', data)` on the server and have the proper listeners on the client side.

Comment: How to re-run a specific part of the socket based on some value change in the agenda trigger?

Comment: You can emit the data in whatever handler you have for the agenda change.